# kivy pass value from one screen to another screen after popup conformation

Tags: python, kivy

I have two screens one have input and other shows the output.When the input is entered and go button is pressed a popup must appear and show 'do you want to transfer the value?'. If No is pressed goto the second screen and show the previous value. if yes is pressed goto the second screen and show the new value in the kivy screen. Need help.

### py

```
from kivy.properties import StringProperty,ObjectProperty
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

class Screen1(Screen):
    text = StringProperty('')

    def changetext(self):
        self.text = self.text11.text
    def erroropen(self):
        Error_Change().open()

class Error_Change(Popup):
    def changetext(self):
        Screen1().changetext()

class Screen2(Screen):
    label_text = StringProperty('')


class screenApp(App):
    pass

screenApp().run()
```

### kv

```
ScreenManager:
    id: screen_manager
    Screen1:
        id: screen_1
        name: 'screen1'
    Screen2:
        name: 'screen2'
        label_text: screen_1.text

<Screen1>:
    text11:text11
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        TextInput:
            id:text11
        Button:
            text: 'Screen 2'
            on_press:
                root.manager.current='screen2'
        Button:
            text: 'Set Value and go to screen 2'
            on_press:
                root.erroropen()
<Error_Change>:
    id:pop3
    title:'Alert!!!'
    size_hint: .65,.4
    auto_dismiss: False
    BoxLayout
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing:0
        padding:[0,0,0,10]
        size:self.size
        Label:
            text:'Do you want to start cycling with this configuration?'
            font_size:20
            bold:True
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            font_size:15
            padding:[30,10,30,10]
            size_hint:1,.6
            spacing:20

            Button:
                text:'Continue'
                on_release:
                    root.changetext()
                    app.root.current='screen2'
                    pop3.dismiss()
                bold:True
                background_normal: ''
                background_color: (.75, .2, .01,1)
            Button:
                text:'Cancel'
                on_release: pop3.dismiss()
                bold:True
                background_normal: ''
                background_color: (.1, .8, 0,1)
<Screen2>:
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: root.label_text
        Button:
            text: 'Screen 1'
            on_press:
                root.manager.current='screen1'
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] to show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why, but it's a very common mistake that you do. It basically comes down to a misunderstanding of the difference between classes and instances in python, or at least which is which when it comes to kivy widgets.

in `change_text`, you create a new Screen1 instance, instead of using the existing one on your app. That will not have any effect, as this new instance is not added to your app (and shouldn't be), and will be destroyed as soon as python understands that it's not used for anything.

What you want, is to get a reference to your existing Screen1 instance, one way to get that is by first getting a reference to your App instance, and use the `ids` attribute of it's `root` attribute (which points to the base of your widget tree).

You can use `App.get_running_app()` to get the "app" object, (same as `app` in kv), and use `app.root.ids.screen_1.change_text()`, with the right parameter. Or you could just bypass this step, and directly call `app.root.ids.screen_1.change_text()` from kvlang.